# Searching for apocalyptic anime series where japan collapses because of plastic-eating microbes

Tags: story-identification, anime

I only ever saw a short sequence, bear in mind that this was more than ten years ago. The art style looked elaborate and rather modern, with intricate backdrops and detailed shading. This is what I remember.

Apocalyptic scenes in Japan, people dying from rampant disease as infrastructure and society collapses. A (Japanese?) heroine is seen negotiating for help with representatives from the US. She is confronted with indifference and outright spite. No help will be provided. She proceeds to blast across the pacific in some futuristic vehicle. Cliffhanger ending.

The credits were not shown, because the TV Channel was eager to show ads.

Can someone identify the series based on this scene?

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2368220.Mutant_59

Comment: That's the big one about plastic-eating microbes... but there does not seem to be an anime version.

Comment: I’m also looking for this anime. I remember plastic melting away, no bottled water, and the microbes spreading thru water. Did you ever find the name?

Comment: Real life...? There is a new PET-eating microbe discovered by scientists ya know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the anime "[Earth Maiden Arjuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Maiden_Arjuna)" episode 12 "The Death of a Nation".

In this episode Japan is destroyed by a bacterium that affects petrochemicals.

### Episode 12 on YouTube

At the end of the episode, Arjuna is leaving Japan, headed across the ocean, in a sort of mech.

[image: Arjuna headed across the ocean]